# Как правильно сказать: "отдать гражданский долг" или "выполнить"?

Tags: стилистика

Как правильно написать: "Отдать гражданский долг" или "выполнить"? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно - **исполнить**.
"Отдать" тут будет плохо стилистически.

Answer (score 2):

Правильны 2 варианта: ВЫПОЛНИТЬ // ИСПОЛНИТЬ ДОЛГ: глаголы ВЫПОЛНИТЬ и ИСПОЛНИТЬ используются как синонимы в значении "осуществить, провести в жизнь (порученное, задуманное)" причем глагол со старославянской приставкой ИС- имеет более возвышенную стилистическую окраску. См.: Ожегов С.И.. Словарь русского языка. --- М., 1982. --- С.148 (долг), 101 (выполнить), 220 (исполнить).

Comment: Как вам удалось дать два ответа в одну тему?
Они мало чем отличаются, свой комментарий повторять не буду.

Comment: У меня большая практика работы с языком, к тому же  всегда под рукой лингвистические СЛОВАРИ, мои верные помощники и советчики (см. ответ выше).

Comment: На этом основании движок форума сделал для Вас исключение из правила "один ответ в одну тему"?

Comment: Движок чувствует людей со словарями и делает им поблажки.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: ВЫПОЛНИТЬ гражданский ДОЛГ. ДОЛГ --- то же, что  ОБЯЗАННОСТЬ. (См.: С.И.Ожегов. Словарь русского языка. --- М., 1982. -- С. 148).
Но: ОТДАТЬ последний ДОЛГ кому-н. (перен.) --- почтить память умершего, прощаясь с ним при погребении. (Там же.)

Comment: Смею заметить, что у Ожегова не указано, с каким глаголом следует употреблять "гражданский долг". Но по факту употребления в профессиональной среде, у юристов, например, или бухгалтеров, долги (долговые обязательства) всё-таки исполняют, а не выполняют.  
В отношении последнего долга - тут да, сложилось употребление с глаголом "отдать".

Comment: У юристов исполняют не долги, а обязанности. У бухгалтеров это будет, пожалуй, рассчитаться с задолженностью (кредиторской / дебеторской - в зависимости кто кому).

Comment: Я много и плотно общался и с теми и с другими. 
В данном случае я не гадаю, говорю ровно то, что знаю.
Исполняют, строго говоря, обязательства. Бухгалтера - бюджетные, например, юристы - алиментные. 
Но обязательства, они - же долги.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше исполнить долг, а не выполнить. Ис- - старославянская приставка, которая в большей степени соответствует высокому слогу, нежели русская вы-.

Comment: Эти приставки нельзя противопоставлять, у них разный смысл. 
Избитый и выбитый.